# Lambda expression to MINUS two string arrays

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to do the equivelent of a SQL MINUS on two string arrays.  Here's the code that I'm trying to replicate:

```
        string returnValue = "";
        foreach (string eachWord in allWords)
        {
            foreach (string ignoreWord in ignoreWords)
            {
                if (eachWord != ignoreWord)
                {
                    returnValue += eachWord;
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to rewrite this as:

```
returnValue = allWords.Minus(ignoreWords);
```

or something equally succinct.  I realize that behind the scenes I'll end up with the same code, but I'm just being pedantic !

Comment: Behind the scenes you will **not** get the same code.  Your code is O(M*N) where M is the size of `allWords` and N is the size of `ignoreWords`.  With a more properly implemented algorithm (say, the algorithm used in Linq's `Except` you can get O(N + M).  The key is to store one collection in a HashSet, which has O(1) searching.  Then you don't have nested loops, you have one loop (add items to set) followed by another single loop (do the searching).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
returnValue = allWords.Except(ignoreWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only the string not an `IEnumerable<string>` , you may do it like this:

```
var res = allWords.Except(ignoreWords);
```

and then ,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       res.ForEach(item => sb.Append(item));
        string ss = sb.ToString();
```

or if you want some separator you may do like this:

```
string concatenatedStr =  string.Join(",", res.ToArray());
```